# Convert Google Maps Elevation output to feet instead of meters

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math, google-maps-api-3

This is only a snippet of code, from my project, but it is currently showing a map and an elevation bar.  The elevation bar is currently showing metric, instead of imperial.  Clearly, I have defined imperial.  Any ideas?

```
     ds.route({
  origin: from,
  destination: to,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
}, function(result, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      fitBounds = true;
      dr.setDirections(result);
    }
});
```

**Update**: Does this information get passed along to google's elevation service?  It seems like if you define imperial here, it should carry through.

Comment: Not sure what this question is in reference to. Do you want to change Google Maps' output to feet? Or do you want to know how to convert meters to feet? In that case, `1 foot = 0.3048 meters`

Comment: I would like to change the output of google maps to feet @Pekka웃

Comment: There seems to be nothing in your code referring to the Google Maps API - what calls are you making where?

Comment: Here is a pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/pwU1wHCC) with the entire code. @Pekka웃

Comment: Please incorporate the relevant parts into the question so it's safe and independent from pastebin. Either way, a Google search for `google maps api km miles` turns up this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/Y33ZJJePGNs which might help

Comment: Not sure that I understand the code good enough myself to do that.  Hopefully someone can follow the pastebin and extract the relevant parts in their answer, and then I can update the question. @Pekka웃

Comment: I will take a look at that link, @Pekka웃 Thanks for sending.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you need to set the `unitSystem` parameter to `imperial`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#DirectionsRequest but I'm not quite sure where exactly to put that (never worked with directions before)

Comment: Imperial sets the units to **MILES** you will need to convert this to feet. ie distance/5280

Comment: @benknighthorse I had a look at your code. Have modified it from metres to yards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code returns metres for elevation.
To convert this to IMPERIAL the following converts metres to feet.

```
var writeStats = function(r) {
  var prevElevation = r[0].elevation;
  var climb = 0;
  var drop = 0;
  var max = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
    var diff = r[i].elevation - prevElevation;
    prevElevation = r[i].elevation;
    if (diff > 0) {
      climb += diff;
      climb = Math.abs(climb / 1) ;//Object to number
      var  climb2 = climb  * 3.2808399;//Metres to feet

    }
    else {
      drop -= diff;
      drop = Math.abs(drop / 1) ;
      var  drop2 = drop  * 3.2808399;

    }

    if (r[i].elevation > max) {
      max = r[i].elevation;
    }
  }
  max = Math.ceil(max);
  $('#climb-drop').text("Climb: " + Math.round(climb2) + " feet Drop: " + Math.round(drop2) + " feet");
  return max;
};
```

[image]

Comment: @benknighthorse finally sorted see new code. Had to change object into number `Math.abs(climb / 1)` then new variable with multiplication `var  drop2 = drop  * 3.2808399`